# Autocomplete don't have effect when using environment variable

Tags: command-line

My os is ubuntu 11.10. In the terminal when i input `cp $HOME/` then type <kbd>TAB</kbd>. It will change to `cp \$HOME/` and won't give any hint about what's in this directory. 
But in vim, it will work just as i want. I heard that vim is using `zsh` instead of `bash`.

Comment: Probably the `$` is escaped, not expanded.

Comment: This is a new "feature" which I've seen appear in Ubuntu since 11.10. Before that, it would expand `$HOME` as soon as you pressed TAB. But I have no solution.

Comment: Vim is not using any shell, vim has it's own completion implementation.

Comment: Try with `zsh`. It has many nice extra features compared to bash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bug: [In natty, bash completion now quotes shell variable references rather than expanding them](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bash/+bug/778627)

See comment #7 for a workaround or this forum post: [Bash auto-complete of environment variables - Comment #7](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/bash-auto-complete-of-environment-variables-613203/#post3055141)

Comment: Obviously, it's the best answer. But i am wondering how do you find it. Do you often check launchpad? Thank you.

Comment: Nope. I just did a couple of searches using keywords that I found in the forum post. That turned up the bug report.